# How to compress image/jpeg by cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

**cloudfront don't support to compress image/jpeg,how can I do it?**

Comment: JPEG is not really a compressible format. It already compresses images.

Answer (score 0):

Use image compression tools:

ImageOptim Tool : https://imageoptim.com/mac

Node module for programatically compression: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-images

Note : CloudFront only support caching of content and media.

You can do only compressing object in gzip format to serve.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

Comment: Can't realize it by cloudfront？

Comment: there is no option to optimise using cloudfront. This is only caching mechanism

Comment: CloudFront currently doesn't gzip image/jpeg (or image/png, or image/gift).